# How to find the values in one column is greater than the values in another column by how many times?

Tags: dax

I have two columns and I need to find how many times the values in one column is greater than the values in another column in DAX.

For Example:

Column_A     Column_B

8.07      0.70

I want to know how many times is Column A(8.07) is greater than Column_B(0.07)?

Answer (score 0):

```
        MyMeasure = COUNTROWS(
                       FILTER(MyTable,
                              MyTable[Column_A] > MyTable[Column_B]))
```